# How does Visual C# differ from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

The Microsoft documentation refers to Visual C# as if its a programming language.( [See this Visual C# Express homepage](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) ) . Is the version use with Visual Express and other microsoft tools somehow different from the standard C# ? Whats the difference ?

Answer (score 3):

Visual C# is the microsoft development environment for C#.  Visual C# is a subset of Visual Studio.  The Express Editions are the free versions of VC#.

The express editions are limited in extensions you can install into the IDE, licenses for redistribution, etc.  But the language itself is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference.

The Visual Express editions of Visual Studio a free, stripped down version of Visual Studio.

The languages, .NET versions all remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

John Gardner ist right. Visual C# is the development environment an C# the language itselft.

Thats confusing for beginners, because a lot of books have titles like "Visual C# 2010" or "C# 4.0". I also have seen a book which uses the title "Visual C# 4.0" which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Express Edition come with some function of the Visual studio Enterprise Edition.

Express Edition is Free to use for learning other version you need to purchase licence.

Now it has Community Edition

More Detail [here](https://www.visualstudio.com).